# How to properly close an AVAudioRecorder file after a crash

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to properly close an audio file that was open and actively recording when the application experienced a crash. A simple way to test this is to start a recording using the simulator, then press stop in Xcode.

What I believe is happening is that the audio file was never closed, so any attempts to open it again for playback causes an error in AVAudioPlayer. So now the file is pretty much useless. I'm hoping to be able to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the audio file format, the information required to properly close the file may have been lost during the app crash and/or termination.

However, for some audio file formats, there may exist tools (non-Apple, commercial, etc.) that attempt to extract audio data from some types of corrupt or broken files.